# Div not going all the way down the screen

Tags: html, css

My code is at the bottom, it does not work because alot of the files are on my computer but it shows the basic concept this are pictures of my website

[Scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL4Lk.jpg)

[Unscrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Tlt.jpg)

So as you can see on the first image that is scrolled down there is a blank space which is annoying since the height is 65%. The second image is just an unscrolled one.

So my question is how can I make it go from 65% to the bottom of the screen. By the way I can not make this `position:fixed` because then I could not scroll through the games when I add more.

By the way for the solution I want to still be able to scroll down the page normally not just have the div.bg be scrollable.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/DBjloQv.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
ul.nav{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:65.5%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
li.nav{
  float:left;
}
a.nav:visited,a.nav:link{
  color:rgb(230,230,230);
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:14px 16px;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a.nav:hover{
  color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
.active{
  color:rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
div.bg{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:65%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
div.game{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:279px;
  height:375px;
  margin:5px 11px;
  border-radius:1px;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/rGCA5cd.png);
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  cursor:pointer;
}
div.gametext{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color:white;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
}
p.gametext{
  color:white;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Home - <?php $activeid=0; include"php/globalvars.php";echo $name;?></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/home.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="bg">
      <div class="game" id="4"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 4</p></div></div>
      <div class="game" id="22"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 1</p></div></div>
      <div class="game" id="19"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Rocket League</p></div></div>
  </div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a href="index.php" class="nav active" onclick="return false;">Logo Here</a></li>
    <li class="nav" style="float:right;"><a href="signin.php" class="nav>Sign In</a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      $href;
      switch($_GET['id']){
        case 4:
          $href="Battlefield4";
          break;
        case 22:
          $href="Battlefield1";
          break;
        case 19:
          $href="RocketLeague";
          break;
      }
      Header("Location: /game/".$href.".php");
    }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way if you want to see my problem size browser to iphone size.

Comment: Is there a reason for setting it to 65%?

Comment: Look at the ran code, thats why.

Comment: Dont want it covering full page.

Comment: Well, you could set it to 100% and give the div.bg a top margin to push it down

Comment: Nvm it just adds empty space.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the top margin flexibly so here's my solution:

```
div.bg{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:10em; //However much that is required
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

Comment: Does not really work because not it has a ton of blank space where no games are.

Comment: Ok that really does not work because when it is scaled down it messes up and stuff.